# Finding languages such that L1⊆L2⊆L3 where L1,L3∉ RE and L2∈ R

Tags: computability, automata

Finding languages such that L1⊆L2⊆L3 where L1,L3∉ RE and L2∈ R 
i am looking for the simplest solution- using a known languages that do not demand
another formal proof.